# Maps elements display as text (class name)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I use WinRt MapControl on Windows Phone 8.1. But when I trying add MapIcon or MapPolyline map elements I get only text like this:

[image]

XAML code looks like this:

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="MapOnScreenControl"
                         MapServiceToken="12345">
            <maps:MapPolyline Path="{Binding Route, Converter={StaticResource RouteToGeopathConverter}}"/>
        </maps:MapControl>
```

What I am doing is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know WinRt, but normally with Map controls, you can't just drop polyline's on the map, you need to host them in a layer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately map elements cannot be added to the map via XAML. You will need to add them within code.

```
MapOnScreenControl.MapElements.Add(new MapPolyline());
```

A trick I like to do is use the viewmodel to add elements to the map by either setting a `Map` property or a `MapElements` property of my viewmodel.

```
private void MapPage_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var vm = DataContext as MapViewModel;
    vm.MapElements = MyMap.MapElements;
}
```

Then within the viewmodel you can add items to the elements.

You can also add a collection of items using the `MapItemsControl`.

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="Map" MapServiceToken="abcdef-abcdefghijklmno">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="Assets/Mappin.png" Height="25"
                        maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="1,0.5" 
                        maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Geopoint}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to use same xaml sample as you describe, but my xaml MapItemControl element don't contain a ItemTemplate property.

Comment: You're using Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Yes, Windows Phone 8.1